# How to remove quotation marks from a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string value returned by a method and it's **within quotation**. As an example **'59'**. Now i want to **remove quotation marks** and give an output as **59**. How can i do it?

> '59' -> 59

Comment: You can use `string.Replace`: `"'59'".Replace("'", "")`

Comment: If you expect quotes to be present in the string as well, then you might want to use substring instead of replace.

Comment: Could it be that you are receiving a json result? In that case you shouldn't mess around with string replacing but simply de-serialize that json data.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I think is to replace the `'` with an empty string:

```
string Quoted = "'59'";
string UnQuoted = Quoted.Replace("'", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another more generic solution to extract numeric values from strings:

```
        string str = "'59'";
        int num = int.Parse(Regex.Match(str, @"\d+").Value); //59
```